# Prove Riemann rearrangement theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing

The theorem of rearrangement says that if $\sum x_n$ is a conditionally convergent series then exists a permutation $\sigma$ of the naturals such that $\sum x_{\sigma(n)}$ converge (or diverge) to any number.

I want to check if my proof is valid.

Let define a canonical ordering of $(x_n)$ such that $x_{2n}\ge 0$ and $x_{2n+1}<0$, $x_{2n+2}\le x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}<x_{2n+3}$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Because $\sum x_n$ is conditionally convergent with the above canonical order we have that $(x_{2n})\downarrow 0$ and $(x_{2n+1})\uparrow 0$ i.e. both subsequences are monotone.

(I dont know how to prove that such canonical order exists for a infinite set. Maybe Im wrong and this canonical order it not constructible.)

Now choose some $x$ and define a permutation $\sigma$ such that:

- $\sigma (0)=0$ and $\sigma (1)=1$
- $\sigma (a)=\sigma(b)\iff a=b$
- $\sigma (2n)=m\iff \sigma(2n-2)<m \land \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} x_k <x,\;\forall n\in\Bbb N_{>0},\; k\in\sigma(\Bbb N)$
- $\sigma (2n+1)=m\iff \sigma(2n-2)<m \land \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} x_k \ge x,\;\forall n\in\Bbb N_{>0},\; k\in\sigma(\Bbb N)$

Then, by construction, $\sum x_{\sigma(n)}\to x$.

By hand it is obvious that such permutation exists (if the described canonical order is possible) but I dont found a clearer way to construct it formally and recursively (I can define a construction using just words but it dont seems too formal). Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

---

Following the comments of @Astyx I will rewrite the way that we construct $\sigma$. Indeed we dont need the previous canonical order, we only need to know that exists infinite positive terms and infinite negative terms in $(x_n)$.

Then I define $\sigma$ in this way

$$x_{\sigma(n)}\ge 0\iff \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x_{\sigma(k)}<x$$

$$x_{\sigma(n)}<0\iff \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x_{\sigma(k)}\ge x$$

for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Then, by construction, due to the fact that $(x_n)\to 0$ we have that

$$\lim \sum_{k=0}^n x_{\sigma(k)}=x$$

What I dont see clearly is how we can define formally the choosing of $n$ such that $\sigma$ is a bijective function on $\Bbb N$.

Comment: The way you define $\sigma$ is very confusing : since $\sigma$ is a permutation you always have $k\in \sigma(\Bbb N)$ don't you ?

Comment: I think it is easier to define $\sigma$ by induction, that is : $$\sigma(n+1) \gt 0 \iff \sum_{k=0}^n{x_{\sigma(k)}}\le x$$

Comment: @Astyx the problem that I see with induction is that this not ensure that the series converges, I mean that $x_{\sigma(n+1)}$ is not bounded. This can define an alternating sequence that doesnt converge, just stay around $x$ chaotically.

Comment: Using the fact that $x_n \to 0$ you can prove that this is not the case (if I am not mistaken) because you can prove that $x_{\sigma(n)} \to 0$ for any permutation $\sigma$

Comment: @Astyx Thanks for the correction. I've deleted my incorrect answer. You can define the canonical ordering, by induction: set $x_{2n}$ to be the greatest non-negative term, and $x_{2n+1}$ to be the least negative term, in the sequence that you haven't yet used. As you pointed out, conditional convergence tells you that the sequence approaches $0,$ so both those values always exist.

Comment: @Mitchell Spector This is not rigorously true, you need only to filter only indice (for instance consider the sequence $1,1,{1\over2},{1\over2},{1\over3},{1\over3}, ...$). But *de facto* you do not even need to arrange them by order, only by sign.

Comment: @Astyx It's apparently too early for me; I should stop posting. I think the comment is fixed now. Use the first number in each case that hasn't yet been used. In any case, there really isn't a problem with building the OP's canonical sequence.

Comment: @Masacroso Does this answer your question ?

Comment: @Astyx I updated the question, take a look please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sketch of the proof :

Assume $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N} \in \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ a real sequence whiches series is semi-convergent.

Let $(x^+_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be the subsequence of the positive terms of $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ and $(x^-_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ the subsequence of the strictly negative terms. Since $\sum x_n$ is semi-convergent, it follows that $\sum_{k=0}^n x^+_k \to +\infty$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n x^-_k \to -\infty$.

Assume $x \in \Bbb R$ a real.

Let's construct a permutation $\sigma$ by induction such that $$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}x_{\sigma(k)} = x$$

For $n\in \Bbb N$, define $\sigma(n)$ such that :

- If $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x_{\sigma(k)}\le x$, then $\sigma(n)$ is the first term of $(x^+_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ that has not been used
- If $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x_{\sigma(k)}\gt x$, then $\sigma(n)$ is the first term of $(x^-_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ that has not been used

Such a construction ensures that $\sigma$ is a permutation (*ie* a bijection) since $\sum_{k=0}^n x^+_k \to +\infty$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n x^-_k \to -\infty$ and any term of $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is either in $(x_n^+)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ or $(x_n^-)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ (but not both).

Now since $\sum x_n$ is convergent, $\sum_{k=n}^{+\infty}x_k \to 0$ as $n$ goes to $+\infty$ and this ensures that $\sum x_{\sigma(n)}$ converges (this is true for any permutation $\sigma$ and is not as obvious as it seems).

Our construction of $\sigma$ ensures that the limit is $x$.

Comment: I see, thank you. My problem here is to define formally "the first term that has not been used", I tried to use the minimum from some kind of set but it seems ugly to construct this thing.

Comment: @Masacroso Yes thank you, I'll edit

Comment: Name $\phi^+$ and $\phi^-$ the extractions that give you respectivly $x^+$ and $x^-$, then $\sigma(n) = \min\{\phi^+(k), k\in\Bbb N, \forall i\in \Bbb \{1, ..., n-1\}, \phi^+(k) \ne \sigma(i)\}$ for the positive case (or something similar)