# How to determine a variable inside the lower and upper bound of a sum inside a infinite sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, riemann-sum

I hope you can help me on a problem I'm working on a long time.

We had to rearrange the alternating harmonic series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$

in such a way, that we get 5.

I split the series up in two new ones. One with the positive numbers $\Bigl(\sum\frac{1}{2i-1}\Bigl)$ and one with the negative numbers $\Bigl(\sum-\frac{1}{2t}\Bigl)$. I also wrote it down in a short formula but I don't know how the determine $\alpha$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Biggl(\sum_{i=(n-1)\alpha+1}^{(n-1)\alpha+\alpha} \frac{1}{2i-1} +\sum_{t=n}^{n} -\frac{1}{2t}\Biggl)=5$$

What is the easiest way to determine $\alpha$?

(My idea was to add positive numbers until I'm over 5, then subtract a negative number so we are below 5, add positive until I'm above 5 again, subtract a negative and so on.

Comment: take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990488/prove-riemann-rearrangement-theorem)

Comment: Your idea is precisely a proof sketch of Riemann's theorem. Whether there's a more explicit way to write down the rearrangement, I don't know.

Comment: @ThePirateBay you can rearrange conditionally convergent series to get any value you want. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: @ThePirateBay We have to rearrange the first series in such a way, that we get 5. I know the riemann theorem and i know how to rearrange, that it will become 1/2 log2 but that doesnt help...

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen we dont have to proof Riemanns Theorem, we have to rearrange in a way, that it converges to exactly 5.

Comment: @MatthiasN. I should have said your idea is a sketch of the theorem for the special case of showing a rearrangement exists that converges to $5.$ So it's right. I just was saying I don't know if there's a 'slick' and easy-to-describe rearrangement like the one for $(1/2)\log 2.$ My guess would be not.

Comment: How you can fine tune the sum of the rearranged series is explained [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5ad3/01a14b77a9538afb0ddb0b7c98c8c9879abd.pdf). You'd need a high asymptotic density of positive terms, only one of a few ten thousand terms may be negative (even denominator).

Comment: @MatthiasN, actually, reading your idea more closely, I'd rephrase: "Add positive terms until we get above five, then add negative terms *till we're below five* (not just one, although I guess in this case I guess will probably just be one term every time), and so on." the fact that the terms diminish in size but that enough of them can sum as big as we want guarantees this will converge to five.