# how does rearranging terms of harmonic series result in different values?

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, conditional-convergence

In the book `In Pursuit of Zeta-3` the author states that rearranging the terms of a harmonic series results in a different sum.

But isn't addition commutative? How is rearraging terms then resulting in different result?

[image: book page]

Comment: Look up Riemann rearrangement theorem.

Comment: Yes, adding two numbers is commutative. And from this you can prove that adding finite numbers of numbers is commutative. And then infinity says "Surprise!".

Comment: Note the "harmonic series with **alternating signs**". The alternating signs are important.

Comment: In addition to the counterexample in *the book cited in the question*, there are a number of proofs of the Riemann rearrangement theorem on this site.  The first I found is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1990488/ .

Comment: Finite addition is commutative, not infinite addition. Actually, if you change only the positions of finitely many values in the infinite sum, the limit will be the same.

Comment: Commutativity is a property of adding two summands. You can extend it by induction to any finite number of summands. But read that proof that you posted there for all to see, there'll be no doubt: commutativity does not extend to an infinite number of summands.